# Python GCSE homework help - password

Tags: python, function, if-statement, while-loop

For my homework I need to make a user registration system in python. I need to make a password section.

[image: Question]

What I am meant to do?.

Here is my code, I can't work out whats wrong:

```
password = input("Please enter your password: ")
passwordl = len(password)
while passwordl <= 8:
    print("password must be more than 8 characters - please try agian")
    password = input("Please enter your password: ")
passworda = password.isalpha()
passwordi = password.isdigit()
while passworda != True or passwordi != True:
    print("password needs to contain digits and characters - please re-enter")
    password = input("Please enter your password: ")
```

The code is in a function btw.

Thanks

Comment: What's your issue?...because I can see some issues at first glance..

Comment: **PLEASE DO NOT POST TEXT AS IMAGES**. Copy and paste the text into your question. Images are not searchable, and can not be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions `isalpha()` and `isdigit()` return true if *all* the members in the string are alphanumeric and digits, respectively.

What you need to do instead is to check if *any* characters in the string have the right properties, for example like this:

```
passworda = any([x.isalpha() for x in password])
passwordi = any([x.isdigit() for x in password])
```

Additionally, you need to redo *all* the checks (both length and character set checks) each time when the password is entered anew.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of following

```
 Password = input("Please enter your password")
```

In the last while loop with the checks over again you would be better just calling the password function as it's more efficient.